# Python Flask + async io

Tags: python, flask, async, asyncio

Tengo una consulta sobre async en python y flask ya que estoy aprendiendolo.

Tengo una app flask sincronica tradicional, pero ahora necesito hacer una funcion async que enviará cientos de request http con asyncio.gather.

Que sucede si en mi endpoint de flask llamo a esta funcion con asyncio.run() como en este caso:

```
async def llamado_asincrono():
  ...
  resultados = asyncio.gather(*requests)

  return resultados

@app.get('/')
def endpoint():
  cosas()
  asyncio.run(llamado_asincrono)
  otras()

  return 200
```

¿Necesitaría un servidor asincronico corriendo Flask? ¿o con un stack clasico también puede correr el asyncio.gather para este request sin afectar el funcionamiento de mi app?

Gracias.

Comment: creo que eso tiene poco que ver, si tu servidor demora demasiado en devolver datos la conexión con el cliente se cierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask no es un framework asíncrono, y por defecto se ejecuta en un solo hilo.

Cuando tu servidor reciba una petición a la ruta `/`, ese hilo pasa a ejecutar la función `endpoint()`. Cuando dentro de ella llamas a `asyncio.run()`, eso pasa a ejecutar un bucle de eventos de la biblioteca asyncio, y dentro de ese bucle de eventos se ejecutan posiblemente diferentes tareas (entremezclándolas de forma asíncrona). Si bien en este caso se crea una sola tarea, que es la que hace la función `llamado_asincrono`, esa tarea puede crear otras (como de hecho parece que estás haciendo, ya que observo un uso de `gather()`).

Sólo cuando todas las tareas del bucle asíncrono hayan terminado, será cuando la función `asyncio.run()` finalice. Por tanto de poco sirve meter `async/await` en este caso, ya que el único hilo de Flask estará ocupado ejecutando `asyncio.run()` hasta que éste retorne, y mientras tanto no puede atender a otros clientes.

Si la tarea `llamado_asincrono` tarda por ejemplo 10 segundos en finalizar, el cliente que solicitó la ruta `/` tardará 10 segundos en recibir la respuesta, y todos los clientes adicionales que hubieran llegado después de él deberán esperar ese tiempo para *empezar* a ser atendidos.

Para este tipo de cosas debes usar otro framework que sí sea asíncrono. Aunque no lo he probado, tiene mucha fama [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), que además es lo bastante similar a Flask para que probablemente te sirva lo que tengas, con modificaciones mínimas.

Por ejemplo, una adaptación del código que muestras iría así:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

async def llamado_asincrono():
  ...
  resultados = asyncio.gather(*requests)

  return resultados

@app.get("/")
async def endpoint():
  cosas()
  await llamado_asincrono()
  otras()

  return 200
```

Ya que FastAPI tiene su propio bucle de eventos, no necesitas usar `asyncio.run()`. En este caso las tareas creadas desde `llamado_asincrono()` son manejadas por el bucle de eventos "al mismo nivel" que las tareas creadas por acceder a los endpoints. Es decir, que mientras `llamado_asincrono()` esté bloqueado por alguna operación de entrada/salida, el bucle de eventos puede pasar a atender a otro cliente.

Las funciones `cosas()` y `otras()` se llamarían "normalmente" (sincrónicamente), pero sería posiblemente recomendable implementarlas como corutinas e invocarlas mediante `await cosas()`, `await otras()` respectivamente, si es que estas funciones tienen bloqueos debido a entrada/salida, o largos bucles de procesamiento que puedas interrumpir cada cierto tiempo con un `asyncio.sleep()` para dar oportunidad de entrar a otra corutina.